# What is the scope of a type variable brought into existence by pattern matching on SomeNat?

Tags: haskell, types, existential-type, type-level-computation

I'm having trouble understanding why this code:

```
-- someNatVal test case
--
-- David Banas <capn.freako@gmail.com>
-- August 5, 2018

{-# OPTIONS_GHC -Wall #-}

{-# LANGUAGE RankNTypes #-}
{-# LANGUAGE ScopedTypeVariables #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeApplications #-}

import GHC.TypeLits
import Data.Proxy

tellNat :: forall n. KnownNat n => Integer
tellNat = natVal (Proxy :: Proxy n)

foo :: Integer -> Integer
foo n =
  let SomeNat (_ :: Proxy m) =
        fromMaybe (error "Negative Nat!") (someNatVal n)
   in tellNat @m

main :: IO ()
main = print $ foo 1 == 1
```

produces this compilation error:

> [1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( someNatValTest.hs,
>   someNatValTest.o )
>
> someNatValTest.hs:22:16: error: Not in scope: type variable ‘m’

As per @Carl, this code:

```
{-# OPTIONS_GHC -Wall #-}

{-# LANGUAGE AllowAmbiguousTypes #-}
{-# LANGUAGE RankNTypes #-}
{-# LANGUAGE ScopedTypeVariables #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeApplications #-}

import GHC.TypeLits
import Data.Maybe
import Data.Proxy

tellNat :: forall n. KnownNat n => Integer
tellNat = natVal (Proxy :: Proxy n)

foo :: Integer -> Integer
foo n =
  case n' of
    SomeNat (_ :: Proxy m) ->
      tellNat @m
  where n' = fromMaybe (error "Negative Nat!") (someNatVal n)

main :: IO ()
main = print $ foo 1 == 1
```

works:

```
dca9047d694f:tmp a594349$ stack runghc someNatValTest.hs
True
```

Comment: `let` does lazy pattern matching, unlike `case` so the rules differ. I guess if one uses lazy patterns as in `cases .. of ~(pattern) -> ...` one would get the similar errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Interesting - usually GHC tells you its brain exploded if you try something like that. I guess in your case, `SomeNat` is only an existential, not a true GADT, therefore you don't get the fun error message.

In any case, you need to match a constructor with a `case` expression instead of a `let` if you want access to types that are hidden inside the data type.

Comment: Thanks, @Carl! Suggestion verified, and fixed code added below original code above.